# merge pandas dataframes vertically without losing column name using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: is there any way to merge 3 different dataframes vertically with different columns and index like shown in image using pandas?]

df1 is first dataframe have columns 1,2,8,9
df2 is second dataframe have columns 3,4
df3 is third dataframe have columns 5,6,7

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with :

```
// horizontally
pandas.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)

// vertically
pandas.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

For more details, you may have a look into [Merge, join, concatenate and compare in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Examples:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C1': ['1', '2', '3'], 'C2': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'C8': ['t', 'u', 'v'], 'C3': ['w', 'x', 'y']})

print (df1)    

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C3': ['4', '5', '6', '12'], 'C4': ['d', 'e', 'f', 's']})

print (df2)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'C5': ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11'], 'C6': ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'], 'C7': ['n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r']})

print (df3)

// horizontally
print (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1))

// vertically
print (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]))
```

Output:

```
//df1
 C1 C2 C8 C3
  1  a  t  w
  2  b  u  x
  3  c  v  y
//df2
   C3 C4
   4  d
   5  e
   6  f
  12  s
//df3
   C5 C6 C7
   7  i  n
   8  j  o
   9  k  p
  10  l  q
  11  m  r
// merge df1 df2 df3 horizontally
    C1   C2   C8   C3   C3   C4  C5 C6 C7
    1    a    t    w    4    d   7  i  n
    2    b    u    x    5    e   8  j  o
    3    c    v    y    6    f   9  k  p
  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   12    s  10  l  q
  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  11  m  r

// merge df1 df2 df3 vertically
    C1   C2   C8   C3   C4   C5   C6
    1    a    t    w  NaN  NaN  NaN
    2    b    u    x  NaN  NaN  NaN
    3    c    v    y  NaN  NaN  NaN
  NaN  NaN  NaN    4    d  NaN  NaN
  NaN  NaN  NaN    5    e  NaN  NaN
  NaN  NaN  NaN    6    f  NaN  NaN
  NaN  NaN  NaN   12    s  NaN  NaN
  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    7    i
  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    8    j
  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    9    k
  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   10    l
  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   11    m
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but I asked for vertically, like exactly shown in image the column 3,4 should come under columns 1,2,8,9 in the output

Comment: @Beginner just wait, I am giving you the solution